# Merge Polylines by Field Attribute & Sum Other Attributes at the same time [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, line, merge

I'm working with a dataset of road links, each link has a flow assigned to it. I have 3 separate shapefiles of these links based on their times - AM, Interpeak and PM peak. I have merged all these into one polyline layer to work with, as ultimately I will need all the time periods in one table.

Unfortunately the dataset has multiple lines for each link, resulting in say 10 different features for one road link. See here:

[image]

What I want to do is:

- Merge all feature links with the same road name AND same time period (eg. AM, Road 1) into a single feature
- Ensure that as I do the above, the sum of the traffic flows is output in the single feature.

EG. I have the following attribute table:

[image]

I need the following output:

[UNIQUE TIME PERIOD] [ROAD LINK AS SINGLE FEATURE] [SUM OF LINK FLOW]

I should end up with 3 time periods, each with the same links and summed traffic flows.

I am at a loose end, having tried various options and I really need some help now!

Comment: Have you tried dissolve?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think I'm using it correctly - I can't seem to get it to keep the right fields/attributes.

Comment: Interesting question!  Can you edit your question to supply a screenshot of your Dissolve tool, showing your options?  Also, it might help if you re-did your attribute table screenshot with the fields stretched a little wider so that the field names are fully readable.

Comment: Partially solved using AGGREGATE function